# 2D Array Input in same line

Tags: c#, asp.net

How I take 2D array input in same line. in C# Console.ReadLine() allow us to take input one at a time .I want to take input as a row

```
int [,] arr = new int[m,n];

for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        arr[i, j] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
}
```

I want to take input this way
2 2,
10 20,
30 40

Answer (score 0):

```
    var delimiter = ' ';
    for(var i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        var row = Console.ReadLine();
        var _arr = row.Trim().Split(delimiter);
        for(var j=0; j<m; j++) {
            arr[j, i] = int.Parse(_arr[j].Trim());
        }
    }
```

Update:

@mike-hofer, wholeheartedly agree with the "error prone and frustrating for users" characteristics of such way of input. I assume this is rather for a quick and dirty testing. Plus, exactly the same approach will be applied if you have to read the array from a file line by line, so there is some broader value in this question.

@rahi-ratul75, the code above does not do any error checking. The most likely error will be an entry which won't parse as an integer. You may want, therefore, to use int.TryParse(,) and, when false, ask to re-enter the line. The main logic, however, is there:

- read the line
- split it into an array
- parse the entry into an integer

Comment: I want to take input as a row in 2D array

Comment: @rahiratul75 you mean you would like to enter three rows separately? 2 2 (Enter) 10 20 (Enter) 30 40 (Enter) ?

Comment: yes brother I want to enter three separately

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: so do i have to check every element of 2d array using int.TryParse ?

Comment: Yes, you have to validate all human input, if you want to use the code for anything other than quick and dirty testing

Answer (score 0):

Entering a two-dimensional array on the command line is going to be error prone and frustrating for users. But if you MUST do it:

1. Figure out what symbols will separate values. (Commas, spaces?)
2. Figure out what symbols will separate array dimensions. (Pipes, perhaps? Whatever you choose, make sure it isn't the same symbol you use for separating values.)
3. Prompt the user for data and capture it into a string.
4. Validate the data.
5. Write a parser that parses your data into a multi-dimensional array.

I'd advise against trying to do this. But I don't dictate your requirements.

Comment: Ok but how i implement it in code ?